# Environment variable for preview deploys with Vercel?

Tags: vercel

Does Vercel have an inbuilt environment variable for preview deploys (as opposed to production)?

I know that you can set these manually for different deployments, but I assumed this was a common enough requirement that there would be something available by default. However I can't find this in the documentation.

Comment: I guess you have found https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables#preview-environment-variables already. What are you trying to achieve that you cannot do with that?

Comment: Link is now https://vercel.com/docs/projects/environment-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`process.env.VERCEL_ENV` will be "preview" for preview deploys.

https://vercel.com/docs/projects/environment-variables